# How can i copy Couchbase data from disk to memory, due to memory increasing?

Tags: couchbase, centos5

Some time ago our Couchbase cluster started to read data from disk, because memory was full. We increased memory amount, but the Couchbase still reads from the disk. Disk reads greatly increases the number of errors in our software. And i'm wondering is there possibility to copy data from disk to memory, so Couchbase can work normally again?

CentOs 5.6
Couchbase v.1.8

Answer (score 0):

As documented here http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-introduction-architecture-diskstorage.html Couchbase tries to keep the dataset in memory. So when you access the document it will be put in memory.

When adding physical memory you will need to also increase the RAM Quota of your cluster/nodes.

Do you have information about the cache misses?

Is what you want is put "all the document" in memory? (do you have enougt RAM?)

Comment: Problem is that i increased memory for cluster and nodes, but resident level stayed at 80% and Couchbase not loading data from disk to memory(i have 60% of memory free now).
I posted this bug to Couchbase JIRA. Will see what they say.